# Python: Plotting a infinite series by only taking finite points

Tags: python, plot, series

I am trying to plot an infinite series by taking only a finite amount of points.  In my case, 3 and 10 points are sufficient.

The equation is the Lagrange power series in `e` the eccentricity.

```
E = Me + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}a_n e ** n
```

where `a_n` is

```
a_n = (1 / 2 ** (n - 1) * \sum_{k = 0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} (-1) ** k / 
      ((n - 2 * k)! * k!) * (n - 2 * k) ** (n - 1) * np.sin((n - 2 * k) * Me))
```

So `\lfloor n/2\rfloor` is latex for the floor function of `n/2`.

The independent variable is `E` and dependent `Me` so the function is not written as one would normal encounter such functions but I don't see a way to explicitly solve for `Me` so that we could write `Me(E)`

So what I have done so far is (see below) which is wrong since it doesn't work.  What can I do get the code and plot working?

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as py
import math
from scipy.misc import factorial as fact

Me = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 50000.0)
e = 0.65
a = [1.0 / 2.0 ** (math.floor(n / 2.0) - 1.0) *
     sum([(-1.0) ** math.floor(n / 2.0) /
          (fact(math.floor(n / 2.0) - k) * fact(k)) *
          (math.floor(n / 2.0) - 2.0 * k) ** (math.floor(n / 2.0) - 1.0) *
          np.sin((math.floor(n / 2.0) - 2.0 * k) * Me)
          for k in range(1, 4, 1)])
          for n in range (1, 4, 1)]

print a

def E2(x):
    return Me + sum(a[n] * e ** n for n in range(1, 4, 1)) - x

fig = py.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(Me, E2(Me))
py.xlim((0, 2 * np.pi))
py.ylim((0, 2 * np.pi))
py.show()
```

With this program, I am getting

```
In [2]: /usr/bin/ipython:17: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_\
scalars
/usr/bin/ipython:17: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
/usr/bin/ipython:17: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in add
[array([ nan,  inf,  inf, ..., -inf, -inf, -inf]), array([ nan,  inf,  inf, ..., -\
inf, -inf, -inf]), array([ nan,  inf,  inf, ..., -inf, -inf, -inf])]
```

Infinity shouldn't be a value at all so I am not sure how that is being derived.

The final error is `list of index out of range`

```
/home/dustin/Documents/School/UVM/Engineering/OrbitalMechanics/lagrangeseries.py i\
n <genexpr>((n,))
     17
     18 def E2(x):
---> 19     return Me + sum(a[n] * e ** n for n in range(1, 4, 1)) - x
     20
     21 fig = py.figure()

IndexError: list index out of range
```

How is this out of range?  Everything is summing from 1 to 3?

Comment: lots of errors there, for starters 1/2**(n-1) evaluates to zero if n is an integer. you need square brackets on your inline loops. google "pyhon tutorial" will bring up tons of good info to get you started..

Comment: @george I added decimal points to everything to fix the integer problem.

Comment: @george I can't find anything on in line loops.  It just says `[]` are list and `()` are tuples where list can be amended and tuples cant

Comment: see list comprehension here http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html.  (note list not tuple)

Comment: @george so I need to do `range[1.0, 3.0, 1.0]` or is it sum[...]?

Comment: you will end up with something like this a=[ ... sum([ ... for k in range(0,kmax) ] ) for n in range(1,3) ]. Note python range(1,3)-> [1,2] not [1,2,3] as you might expect and range needs integer args. a now is a list so in the return statement you'll need a[n]

Comment: @george I updated the op per your suggestion.  If I want to sum from 1 to 3, I need have 1 - 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't need to use the floor function due to the way division works in Python.

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as py
from scipy.misc import factorial as fact

e = 0.65


def E(M):
    return (M + sum((1.0 / 2.0 ** (n - 1) *
                     sum((-1) ** (k) / (fact(n - k) * fact(k)) *
                         (n - 2 * k) ** (n - 1) *
                         np.sin((n - 2 * k) * M)
                         for k in range(0, n / 2, 1))) * e ** n
                         for n in range(1, 4, 1)))


M = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 50000.0)

fig = py.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(E(M), M)
py.xlim((0, 2 * np.pi))
py.ylim((0, 2 * np.pi))
py.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

the indices in the range values should be increased by one for the k counter, so instead of:

for k in range(0, n / 2, 1)

it should be:
for k in range(0, n / 2+1, 1)

otherwise for n =4 range(0, 2, 1) returns 0,1 and not 0,1,2 as needed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).